# PHP functions only called once?

Tags: debugging

I have written a tiny module with a custom block.
The contents of the block is created in the build() function. That function creates the HTMl, which is rendered. I can see that code changes have effect: after a update.php run, the resulting HTML reflect the changes.

But that function has strange behavior. The first thing I do in it is displaying the current url with

```
   $html = '<p>URL: ' . \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri()) . '</p>'
   .....
   return $html;
```

The strange thing is this function always displays the same URL, no matter the actual current url. Only updating the cache can change the path. After that update, the output will remain the same until the next update. Why is this? Is the output of functions cached as well?

Something similar happens when I try to debug the code and write data to a temporary file:

```
file_put_contents ( '/tmp/zphp1', "$html\n", FILE_APPEND );
```

The file is only written once: right after an update.php-run. 
Why is drupal/php not executing all code? What can I do to examine variables in order to see what is happening?

Comment: You really should use a debugger like xdebug instead of create .txt log files (it just adds extraneous code) or write to a logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by asking the question, I almost answered it. It is indeed the result of caching. So when cached, several function calls have no effect. LIke writing to a file, like getting the request url.

When the block is *not* cached, everything works as expected. It is rather confusing behaviour for a newbe like me; caching is default *on*.

caching can be turned off in the output array of the build() function:

```
return array(
        '#markup' => "<p> this is a test</p>",
        '#cache'    => array ( 'max-age'   => 0 ), 
      ),
```